# How to get the last four characters of a string whose length may change in Python

Tags: python

My string coming in could be really any length i just need the last four characters:

```
string = asdfPALD
string = asddasdfBLCA
```

Comment: Do you want the variable name or string content? the latter is `yourString[-4:]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `string[-4:]`:

```
string = "asdfPALD"
```

`string[-4:]` would equal `'PALD'`

Answer (score 4):

Python has positive and (as bizarre as it sounds) negative indexes. The negative indexes start at the end of the string (as you can see in the image). So if I want to get the last element of a string (regardless of the length of the string) it would be `my_string[-1]`.

[image]

To get a `slice` of a string in Python, the sintaxis is `my_string[i:j]`, where `i` is the beginning index and `j` is the ending index (without including `j` in the result). If you omit the first index (`i`), it will start from the beggining (index 0) and if you omit the last index (`j`), it will go all the way until the end of the string.

Knowing this, you can rapidly assume that, in order to get the last 4 elements of the string, you would have to do:

```
my_string[-4:]
```

Comment: A better illustration would have the index numbers shifted half a character width to the left so that they line up with the gap between the characters. Make like you are slicing a string of sausages -- you do it BETWEEN two sausages, not through the middle of a sausage.

Comment: good suggestion @JohnMachin, I didn't actually make the image, it was used in a `Google Python class`.

Comment: If it was a good suggestion, why did you muck it up and then delete it? What is the relevance of the source of the image?

Comment: @JohnMachin, I realized it was redundant with the image. Besides, editing is just for correcting, not for adding stuff, right? Why did I mention the source of the image? .. why not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`string[-4:]`

This counts from the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Range assignment?

```
str0 = asdfPALD
chunk = str0[len(str0)-4:]
```

Where `[:x]` and `[x:]` would signify the start of the string up to index `x`, or the end of the string down to index `x`.

Answer (score 0):

For a better understanding of slicing (as opposed to indexing), it is helpful to think in terms of slice positions, not in terms of indexes. Slices are made by chopping *between* elements.

```
   H   e   l   l   o 
 |   |   |   |   |   | 
 0   1   2   3   4   5   
-5  -4  -3  -2  -1
```

So [1:-1] produces "ell", [-4:] produces "ello"